# Thousand separator Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I can use this to get desired format:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(12345,'99G999') "Amount" FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_CHAR(123456,'999G999') "Amount" FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_CHAR(1234567,'9G999G999') "Amount" FROM DUAL;
```

Is there a method where you don't have to check the length like this?:

```
select case
when length(my_number) = 5 then TO_CHAR(my_number,'99G999')
when length(my_number) = 6 then TO_CHAR(my_number,'999G999')
```

Comment: You just need enough 9s (and Gs) for the longest value you expect to handle. Extra leading ones don't matter - except they add spaces to the result by default. Why do you think you need the case expression?

Answer (score 6):

Using `9` in the model (as opposed to `0`) means you don't get leading zeros, so you can use the same model for all of those:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(12345,'9G999G999') "Amount" FROM DUAL;

Amount    
----------
    12,345

SELECT TO_CHAR(123456,'9G999G999') "Amount" FROM DUAL;

Amount    
----------
   123,456

SELECT TO_CHAR(1234567,'9G999G999') "Amount" FROM DUAL; 

Amount    
----------
 1,234,567
```

You just need enough `9`s (and `G`s) for the longest value you expect to handle.

If you don't want the leading spaces - including the one that's there in all of those as a placeholder for a potential minus sign for negative values - you can add the `FM` 'fill mode' [format model modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(12345,'FM999G999G999G999') "Amount" FROM DUAL;

Amount          
----------------
12,345

SELECT TO_CHAR(123456,'FM999G999G999G999') "Amount" FROM DUAL;

Amount          
----------------
123,456

SELECT TO_CHAR(1234567,'FM999G999G999G999') "Amount" FROM DUAL; 

Amount          
----------------
1,234,567
```

Comment: or to_char(number,'FM999,999,999,999.09' )

Comment: @HaoHao - the question used the G placeholder, presumably on purpose to allow for different session NLS settings; and didn't seem to want decimals. But yes, you can use whatever format you need, and use fixed commas and periods instead G/D if you prefer and it's appropriate for everyone who will run the query.

Comment: I want reverse, How to remove thousand separate through query?

Comment: @c.sankhala - please ask a new question with all the necessary details, sample data and expected results. Including whether you want to still have a string or a real number result. (But you can try first with `to_number()` and `to_char()`...)